# How can I run site js function with custom arguments?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, phantomjs

I need to scrape google suggestions from search input. Now I use selenium+phantomjs webdriver.

```
search_input = selenium.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@id='lst-ib']")
search_input.send_keys('phantomjs har python')
time.sleep(1.5)
from lxml.html import fromstring
etree = fromstring(selenium.page_source)
output = []
for suggestion in etree.xpath(".//ul[@role='listbox']/li//div[@class='sbqs_c']"):
            output.append(" ".join([s.strip() for s in suggestion.xpath(".//text()") if s.strip()]))
```

but I see in firebug XHR request like [this](https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=serp&hl=en-UA&gs_rn=64&gs_ri=serp&tok=1yZuCM_-3JaE4SLqJRPUjQ&pq=phantomjs%20har%20python&cp=9&gs_id=6mr&q=phantomjs&xhr=t). And response - simple text file with data that I need. Then I look at log:

```
selenium.get_log("har")
```

I can't see this request. How can I catch it? I need this url for using as template for requests lib to use it with other search words. Or may be possible run js that initiate this request with other(not from input field) arguments, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with Python+Selenium+PhantomJS only.

Here is the list of things I've done to make it work:

- pretend to be a browser with a head by changing the PhantomJS's User-Agent through *Desired Capabilities*
- use [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits)
- ask for the direct https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=phantomjs+har+python url

**Working solution:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver


desired_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
desired_capabilities["phantomjs.page.customHeaders.User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; LG-LU3000 Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=phantomjs+har+python")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# focus the input and trigger the suggestion list to be shown
search_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q")))
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
search_input.click()

# wait for the suggestion box to appear
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul[role=listbox]")))

# parse suggestions
print "List of suggestions: "
for suggestion in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul[role=listbox] li[dir]"):
    print suggestion.text
```

Prints:

```
List of suggestions: 
python phantomjs screenshot
python phantomjs ghostdriver
python phantomjs proxy
unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver
```

Comment: Thanks. This version is faster than mine, but sometimes I get a blank list. I know about wait conditions in selenium, but old good time.sleep() works better in this case

Comment: @ElRuso well, the problem with having a `sleep()` call there is that it really make things slower and less reliable. Explicit wait would stop wait right after the expected condition evaluates to true.